# Can I get source URL from Google search if I switch to HTTPS myself?

Tags: url, google-search, https

HTTPS cloaks the keywords, but I've read that by enabling HTTPS on my site I may at least get the source URL's - if the browser goes from HTTPS -> HTTPS it does not drop the source url in the packet header, but going HTTPS -> HTTP does end up dropping it.

Is it true? Should I invest into a SSL certificate so that I may get at least some valid data for my eshop?

Comment: Are you asking if Google will send the whole set of information on the referer?

Comment: No, I only want the full source url from which the visitor came to my site.

If he came from https://google.com/search=word1+word2 I want to see the full link, not only https://google.com

Comment: The _HTTP Referer_ string.

Comment: As w3d said and I asked, that information is sent on the referer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can read in the post [Making search more secure](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/10/making-search-more-secure.html) from 2011, Google stopped sending that information if used with HTTPS. Back then, HTTPS was an option to be used, now, they switched the whole system to HTTPS, that means that no more information about the search.

Google announced in 2012 that it will switch the whole system to HTTPS, you can read about it on this post, [Bringing more secure search around the globe](http://insidesearch.blogspot.com/2012/03/bringing-more-secure-search-around.html)

Comment: That's currently still the case. Technically a referrer could be forwarded if both sites use TLS (HTTPS), but that is not done for these queries on Google's side.